# Model class/subclasses where the subclass type is not known a priori in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am using C++.
`Vehicle` is a class and `Car`, `Truck`, `Ship` are its subclasses.

Imagine that I have a file `file.vechicle` containing information about a `Vehicle` object, and one of the first information of this file is if the vehicle is a `Car`, a `Truck` or a `Ship`.

The format of the file changes accordingly of the vehicle the file is describing.

I defined a static method in `Vehicle` which takes as input a `.vehicle` file, then it determines if the file is describing a `Car`, a `Truck` or a `Ship` and so it calls a private method in the corresponding class to build the object from the file.
Finally the static method returns the correct object, so a `Car` if the file is describing a car, and so on.

Is it possible to achieve the same thing but without introducing a static method, so simply calling the constructor of `Vehicle` and having `Vehicle` changing its identity accordingly to the content of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, C++ objects don't change their most derived types (this behaviour can be emulated more or less easily, for some performance cost, as usual, and for the price of following conventions). You're using something of a Factory pattern, in C++ (and many other languages) its stereotypical implementation is done via static methods returning boxed polymorphic types.

One typical solution would be for the `Vehicle` type to encapsulate internally the concrete implementation. This allows to even construct it:

```
class Carrier {
public:
    virtual void go() = 0;
    virtual ~Carrier() {}
};

class Car: public Carrier;
class Ship: public Carrier;

struct Vehicle /* you can even add ': Carrier' here, just don't make Vehicle run on itself */
{
     Vehicle(std::string const &spec): impl(spec == "car"? new Car : new Ship) {}
     void go() { return impl->go(); }
private:
     std::unique_ptr<Carrier> impl;
};
```